# How to create a column of Maps in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I essentially have an SQL table that is similar to

[image]

And I want to create a table that looks like:

[image]

where essentially each cell in the map column contains a map where the key is the receiver ID and the value is the Quantity from the first table. How would I go about doing this using SQL. I know I have to use some function like map_from_entries() but I am not sure how.

The actual table I want to operate on is a lot more complicated but this simplified version still revolves around the same principle.

Comment: Look at using - JSON_OBJECTAGG - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-objectagg.  Also do not post data as image rather put it as text in the question, so it helps people trying to answer form a test case easily by copying from the data in question

Comment: Postgres or MySQL? The solution will be quite different

Answer (score 1):

Sample query -

```
select sender,json_objectagg(receiver,quantity)
from send_rec
group by sender;
```

Refer fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bL3NDAiHKF4NEPB9rqMhtc/0)

Answer (score 0):

In mySQL 8.0:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT sender_id, receiver_id, CONCAT(receiver_id, ':', quantity) AS rec_qty, qty
    FROM maps_tab
    
)
SELECT sender_id, CONCAT('{', GROUP_CONCAT(rec_qty ORDER BY sender_id, receiver_id), '}') AS map
FROM cte
GROUP BY sender_id
```